# In multimodule maven project, how to prevent error if a plugin is not defined for every submodule?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a multimodule maven project, and I need to launch it through
    mvn clean install liferay:liferay

Since some of the submodules haven't the liferay plugin inside, I have this error: 
    [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'liferay' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\xxxxxxx.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

How can I let Maven call liferay:liferay only on modules which support it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Than you shouldn't call the lifecycle from the root of your multi-module build. 
You can use to call it from the root like this.

```
mvn -pl ModuleWhichContainsConfigForLifeRay liferay:liferay
```

But this will only work correctly if you do a mvn install before.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `profile` in the pom for Liferay modules, something like this:

```
 <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>liferay-modules</id>
        <modules>
            <module>MyPortlet</module>
                <module>MyHook</module>
        </modules>
      </profile>
  </profiles>
```

to run liferay plugin only for this modules, start:

```
   #/> mvn clean package liferay:deploy -P liferay-modules
```